# How to rotate object while moving in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript, quaternions

I need to rotate car along the path, but the code doesn't work correct. It moves as a firework. I guess that the problem is in moving from z to x axis. I dont have enough knowledge to solve this problem. Help!

[image]

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Transform StartPoint;
    public Transform[] EndPoints;
    public Transform[] AngleWaypoints;
    public float MoveSpeed;


    private Transform TargetPoint;
    //private Transform EndPoint;
    private float DistanceToPoint = 0f;
    private int RandomValue;
    private Transform[] Waypoints;
    private int wpIndex = 0;
    private Quaternion lookRotation;
    private Vector3 direction;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        RandomValue = Random.Range (1, EndPoints.Length);

        int count = 0;
        switch (RandomValue) {
        case 0:
            //Waypoints = StartPoint + EndPoints [RandomValue];
            count = 2;
            Waypoints = new Transform[count];
            Waypoints [0] = StartPoint; 
            Waypoints [1] = EndPoints[RandomValue];
            break;
        case 1:
            //Waypoints = StartPoint + AngleWaypoints + EndPoints[RandomValue];
            count = 2 + AngleWaypoints.Length;
            Waypoints = new Transform[count];
            Waypoints [0] = StartPoint;
            for(int i=0;i<AngleWaypoints.Length;i++){
                Waypoints [i + 1] = AngleWaypoints [i];
            }
            Waypoints [count-1] = EndPoints[RandomValue];

            break;
        }

        TargetPoint = Waypoints [wpIndex];

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        DistanceToPoint = Vector3.Distance (transform.position, TargetPoint.position);
        if (DistanceToPoint > 1) {
            direction = (TargetPoint.position - transform.position)/2 + transform.position;

            Vector3 dir = TargetPoint.position - transform.position;
            lookRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(dir);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp (transform.rotation, lookRotation, Time.deltaTime);
            Vector3 v = direction / DistanceToPoint * MoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
            transform.Translate (v);

        } else {
            wpIndex++;
            if (wpIndex > Waypoints.Length - 1) {
                wpIndex = 0;
                Destroy(this.gameObject);
            }
            TargetPoint = Waypoints[wpIndex];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used this code sometime ago and it worked

```
void Update () {
    if (this.isMoving){
        if(Vector3.Distance(walkDestination, transform.position) > 0.2f){
            float step = 0f;
            step = this.speed * Time.deltaTime;
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, walkDestination, step);

            Vector3 rotationDestination = this.rotateDestination;
            Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(rotationDestination - transform.position, Vector3.up);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, targetRotation, Time.deltaTime * 6.0f);
        }else{
            //Arrived to destination
        }
    }
}
```